# Bug with dismissing flags

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, moderator-tools

I think I found a minor, yet reproducible bug, with the moderator tools.

1. Goto flags page.
2. Take no further action on a flag.
3. Decline the flag
4. Click "other".
5. Start to type reason.
6. Erase reason.
7. Click any other flag type.

Voila.  The text box still has focus and <kbd>Decline</kbd> is inactive.  You can also reproduce it by skipping steps 5 and 6.  If you give something else focus (ie, click elsewhere) before selecting the other flag, then it works as normal.

Comment: Reproduced in Firefox 16.0.1 on XP.  You can reactivate the Decline button if you type something into the Other text box and choose a different radio button.  Or you can just close the dialog and start over, so there are work-arounds.

Comment: I can't repro this with Firefox 19, but I do see something weird in Chrome 25. Funnily enough you need to type exactly 3 characters for this to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you.

This is done and the fix should go out in the next deploy.